# need to hardcode a column in Hive with a custom word appending along with a column_name from a table

Tags: sql, hive

```
select distinct 'CART-data-map_val.role_name' as ProdMN
from VRN_544.RLT_001 AS mk_roles
JOIN VRMM.map_valxx AS map_val
   ON ( Upper(Trim(map_val.role_name)) = Upper(Trim(mk_roles.rltx_02)) )
```

so, CART-data is the word which should append to the role_name into  ProdMN column

ProdMN column Example -  CART-data-map_val.role_name - 1- CART-data-reducer-role
2- CART-data-modular-role

Answer (score 0):

how about using concat ?:

```
select distinct concat('CART-data-',map_val.role_name) as ProdMN
from VRN_544.RLT_001 AS mk_roles
JOIN VRMM.map_valxx AS map_val
   ON ( Upper(Trim(map_val.role_name)) = Upper(Trim(mk_roles.rltx_02)) )
```